# Is it a good idea to synchronize a Git project via Syncthing?

Tags: git, version-control, synchronization, data-synchronization, syncthing

I am thinking about synchronizing a Git project via Syncthing but I assume this is a bad idea as there are hidden files.

Can you confirm this? Or will Syncthing do this correctly?

Comment: Probably not. There's a lot of repository local stuff that you would not want to be synced between machines (think worktree paths, `HEAD`, the index, ...).

Comment: Feels like an XY-problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Seems counter intuitive to use a 3rd app to sync git as it in itself is desined to be distributed.

Comment: I am trying to find an origin for my repositories in a self-hosted, private way. Syncthing was one idea - it turns out a bad one. I am also not very good at devops so I am looking for a very easy setup without an extra server or a cloud solution. It is difficult to find something like that I guess.

Comment: @fredrik Synchronizing a Git repository across machines is a straightforward need. And being able to synchronize all kinds of files and directories—instead of special-casing `.git`—is also a straightforward need. (But then it turns out to be impractical for technical reasons.)

Comment: @Guildenstern Then do it with the tools built in tools in git... it has the tools you need right there.

Comment: @fredrik Yes, that’s the answer to the question. But the premise of the question is completely understandable. If I want to synch. my home directory—including all Git repositories—my first wish would be to do everything with one synch. tool. It would not be to painstakingly go through each kind of file format, DB format, VCS format etc. and see how to do everything individually with (what would become) some bespoke program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you should never synchronize a Git repository via any sort of continuous file synchronization utility, including Syncthing or any similar utility, such as Dropbox or iCloud.  That's because Git writes data in a very particular order in order to preserve the integrity of the repository, and any sort of synchronization while the repository is not completely idle can corrupt it.

Any sort of continuous file syncing utility will sync as it sees operations happen, but it doesn't and can't guarantee that the operations will happen in the exact order that Git did them, which makes it impossible to preserve the required invariants.

If you do this anyway, the repository may end up corrupt, or you may see problems with duplicated files, files which end up reappearing after being deleted, or other hard-to-reason-about problems.

It is safe to use something like rsync *as long as the repository is completely idle*.  That means that no Git processes are running, including `git gc` or any processes invoked by your editor or shell.  Note that if you do this, due to the nature of the Git index, `git status` will have to re-read all of the files next time you sync.

It is also, of course, safe to use `git push`, `git fetch`, and `git bundle` at any time to transfer data.